# Well designed Open Source WPF Applications

Tags: c#, .net, software, wpf

I'm just wondering if anyone knows about some well designed .NET Open Source Applications using WPF?

I have already tried to search at the usual sites like GitHub and Sourceforge, but I wasn't very satisfied by the results at all.

Actually I'm interested in the right usage of MVVM, Data Binding etc. in the context of relatively large Software (at least more than the few lines of sample code, you will find at most Tutorials and Books). Also ORM with NHibernate lies in my main concern.

Currently I also do have the overall impression WPF is not used very extensively at all, am I right with that? 
Which closed source (commercial) Software Products are out there, using it?

Comment: If it's proficiency in the MVVM pattern and it's associated data binding goodness, you may want to look to a web application using knockout.js javascript library. It has those and has a longer shelf life than WPF at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio is built using WPF. WPF is typically used for internal Line-of-Business applications in businesses of different size. The thing is that you don't need a large application to showcase proper use of MVVM and Data Bindings. Also it's not an open-source kind of technology. What would you build with it that would be useful to a wide range of people? A CMS? A graphics editor?

Check CodeProject: https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Acodeproject.com+mvvm

The projects will not be big but could be less trivial than quick tutorial samples, for example:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/484616/MVVM-Diagram-Designer

Answer (score 0):

I started developing an Open Source application in WPF as a showcase for WPF and MVVM. I didn't get around to finishing but it does have a lot of the structure in place for anyone to get an understanding of how all the pieces interact:

https://github.com/smclark/DriverManager

Obviously it's not perfect, but it was something I wanted to do just to get it all down somewhere.

Comment: _"Obviously it's not perfect"_ -- how does this answer the question asked? "_Well designed_ etc"

Comment: I didn't say it wasn't well designed.